# React Searchbar history push to another page but with a component

Tags: reactjs

I have a search bar and on onSubmit I want to redirect the user to another page but I want input value to be passed with them, preferably as prop.

```
<AsyncSearch
  filter
  options={items}
  onSubmit={(inputValue) =>
    history.push("/SearchPage")
  }
/>
```

Something similar to this.

```
<AsyncSearch
  filter
  options={items}
  onSubmit={(inputValue) =>
    history.push("/SearchPage")
    <SearchPage value={inputValue} />
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass the value as a `param` or `query parameter`, and in `useEffect` hook of `SearchPage` component, receive it from the route and do whatever you intend to.

```
<AsyncSearch
  filter
  options={items}
  onSubmit={(inputValue) =>
    history.push(`/SearchPage/${inputValue}`)
  }
/>
```

Obviously you'll have to change your route to something like this:

```
<Route path="/SearchPage/:value" component={SearchPage} />
```

and in your `SearchPage`:

```
import {useState, useEffect, useParams} from 'react';

function SearchPage(){
 useEffect(()=>{
   const inputValue = useParams().value;
   // do whatever with this inputValue
 },[])
}
```